# Getting Response 429 when testing an instagram link with a user account in the URL

Tags: python, python-requests

I wanna ask if there might be a problem in the requests library.

When i tried to run this code the response is `200`

```
response = requests.get('https://instagram.com/', params=[('q', 'requests+language:python')],)
response
```

> <Response [200]>

But when i tried to test it with a link that has a username in it, it got error `429`

```
response = requests.get('https://instagram.com/Nike/', params=[('q', 'requests+language:python')],)
response
```

> <Response [429]>

I've tested it on google to try out this link on the internet `https://instagram.com/Nike/` and it works normally, there's no connection problem when trying to connect to that site.

[image: Testing on the internet]

What's the cause of the problem, is it from the server side, or is there something wrong with the requests library?

Comment: 429 Error is a "Too Many Requests" error. Did you use your code in a loop?

Comment: Nope i didn't do any loop at all in the code, i only did it on just 1 account @SoyNeko

Answer (score 0):

Response 429 means that you sent too many requests in given amount of time.
When I run code above:

```
response = requests.get('https://instagram.com/Nike/', params=[('q', 'requests+language:python')],)
print(response)
```

I get:

```
 <Response [200]>
```

Comment: But i'm very confused, i only did it on just 1 account? i haven't done any loop command at all

Comment: It's not about account, but about your IP address. You have sent too many request from one IP address. If you are using VPN you can just change your IP and check if it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).